# Javascript select from html by using alt tag

Tags: javascript, html

i need a to make javascript select and click an image from an alt tag
this is the code that i need to select and click with javascript
`<img alt="cat" src="img1.jpg">`

this is what i tried to do
`document.querySelector('cat').click`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector should be `img[alt="cat"]`:

```
document.querySelector('img[alt="cat"]')
```